# How can I obfuscate a private method viewModifier in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In my SwiftUI app, I use custom fonts and want to adjust the height between the lines of text.  I know I could use attributed text, but that is a lot of code modification compared to use the lineHeightMultiple viewModifier as a single "one liner".

I understand that calling private methods could get me rejected during an app submission, so I would like to figure out a way to obfuscate it like you can do in objective C by calling a method using a string and breaking it up or some other method.

Here is my current working private method call:

```
Text( "Hello world long text really long text" )
  .frame(width: 100)
  ._lineHeightMultiple(0.8)
```

I would like to find a solution that would allow me to call the lineHeightMultiple modifier using a string or string based selector such as:

```
Text( "Hello world long text really long text" )
  .frame(width: 100)
  .modifier( PrivateModifier("_line" + "Height" + "Multiple", 0.8) )
```

I tried calling methods on the view by a selector and was not able to get the right combinations of object and responses.

I am expecting to be able to call the private class modifier in a way that wont be directly searchable in the source code as "lineHeightMultiple"

Comment: While it might require a bit of up-front math, the [`lineSpacing(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/linespacing(_:)) modifier does appear to be public; it's not a multiplier like `lineHeightMultiple` but maybe you can use it to sidestep this issue altogether.

Comment: lineSpacing does not work with custom fonts, which my app has, and lineMultiple does